# Are there use-cases for mutable public fields?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I want to know if there might be use cases where public fields are justified (for mutable values) or it should be avoided at all costs and getters/setters should be always used.

Supposed there is a DTO(Data Transfer Object)/Java Bean which does no have any logic, just holding data (to add more this might part of a protocol which does not change, only enhance). 
There are effectively no implementation details that exist to be encapsulated because there is no implementation, just data.
Also suppose Bean Validation framework is used for validating the object via annotations so there is no purpose of having setters for validating logic.

Why would the setters and getters bother me?

It's more easy to read without setters/getters; fields, especially for inner classes (you don't have to scroll through to setters and getters to reach the other fields). Also it's more clear to have `user.password` rather than `user.getPassword()` as in Groovy.

I know about project Lombok; but I already have lots of annotations from Bean Validation.

So to make the question clear: might the above scenario be justified for public fields or is it still better to have setters/getters? **And why?**

Comment: Rule of thumb: Always start with the most restrictive modifier, change it only when you *must* to: "[*Use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a particular member. Use private unless you have a good reason not to.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)"

Comment: This scenario is justified and in earlier java versions, I have seen lot of constant or pure data objects defined this way in the projects I worked. The one issue I feel is of convention. There are developers who conventionally follow getter and setter and it may cause some loss of readability for them. The other issue is future changes. If at all you need some conversion logic (sclae or other operations) then it may get better underneath getter ot setter.

Comment: @MarounMaroun These rules of the thumb have reasons behind; and I completely agree with yours, in scenarios where you have logic to encapsulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current opinion is that you should **not** have mutable public fields.

It derives from the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) from two different directions.

First, it is common practice to have all fields private with access only via getters and setters. There is so much code out there that does this it is *surprising* when you come across code that doesn't.

Second, it gives you predictability. You can **guarantee** that no-one will change the fields anywhere else other than in your setter. You can therefore put a break-point on the setter and **know** that every change to that field will hit the break-point.

There are - however - pure data situations like you describe where it is tempting to make the fields public, and even rarer, not final.

I have in my toolbox a class `Pair` which has public fields:

```
public class Pair<P, Q> {

    // Exposing p & q directly for simplicity. They are final so this is safe.

    public final P p;
    public final Q q;

    public Pair(P p, Q q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }
```

Comment: Approved for first argument; really great. The second argument does not always hold because of dependency-injection frameworks (CDI, Spring, Guice etc. - `@Inject`, `@Autowired`) when choosing injections on fields; they use reflection and avoid the setters.

Comment: The current opinion of who? There's a debate over accessors/mutators. I don't consider it settled. I personally tend to write them, but I think your answer is dogmatic.

Answer (score 1):

A common case is that, sometime at the middle of implementation or execution, you find that yours records end with an empty username.

Now, you either:

- search all the places were the property is assigned to find where it is being assigned a null. It may be 20 places, and most probably, it wont be a `user.userName = null` but a `String userName = null; ..... user.userName = userName`.
- Add a check to your `setUserName()` method that launches an exception when it tries to set a null value. You get the complete stacktrace, and the operation of the program is stopped *before* introducing bad data to your persistence layer.

So, the use-case for directly accessing properties is when you are sure that there are (and there will be) absolutely no bugs in your code.

I'll stick with setters.

Additionally, some (many) frameworks rely in the use of setters and getters to access properties.

Comment: I already use dependency injection frameworks (for example CDI, Spring, Guice) sometimes with field injections; these also avoid setters. Also, at the problem at hand the classes are part of a protocol, so the data is automatically set by some kind of a framework/tool for the whole message. It can be compared for example with REST JSON API; when you receive the user details over HTTP your don't call the setter for user phone explicitly but the phone number is set by Jackson/Gson or which library you is used for converting the whole JSON to POJO.

Answer (score 0):

> might the above scenario be justified for public fields or is it still better to have setters/getters?

The scenario appears to be that you are bothered by scrolling through getters and setters. That's not a good reason in my book, but if you can keep these classes package-private or private nested classes, then it's OK by Joshua Bloch because the scope of potential future changes.

**Effective Java Item 14:** In public classes, use accessor methods, not public fields

> If a public class exposes its
>   data fields, all hope of changing its representation is lost, as client code can be distributed
>   far and wide.
>
> However, **if a class is package-private or is a private nested class, there is
>   nothing inherently wrong with exposing its data fields** - assuming they do an adequate job of describing the abstraction provided by the class.

Personally I'm a little stricter and the rule of thumb I follow is fields must not be visible outside the *compilation unit*. e.g:

```
public class Outer {
    private int fieldMustBePrivate;

    public class PublicNested {
        private int fieldMustBePrivate;
    }

    private class PrivateNested {
        int fieldOkToBePackagePrivate;
    }

    public void exampleUsage() {
        PrivateNested privateNested = new PrivateNested();
        privateNested.fieldOkToBePackagePrivate = 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I've said, talking about encapsulation does not make any sense because the given classes have no logic which could be encapsulated. There is just data which is part of a public protocol, so no reason to hide anything.

Comment: I mentioned it once and I've taken it out, as it was not the main point at all.

Comment: What was the last public API in Java you used that had mutable public fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are:

- Performance
- Code brevity

Calling a function (accessors/mutators are functions) might not seem a big deal, but when translated to assembly code it means you will have to push the function parameters to the stack, push the return address to the stack, execute a CALL function, execute the function body, then push the result to the stack, pop the original parameters, pop the return address and go to the original address... This varies slightly depending on the calling convention and I might have enumerated the steps in the wrong order, but in general you do have overhead when calling a function.

So for such a stupid function like a getter/setter that probably consist of just one or two assembly instructions, the overhead is of the same order of magnitude than the payload and probably greater. If you are developing a game or any other software with high performance requirements, getting rid of function calls is one of the optimization techniques.

About the second use case, code brevity, getter and setter that do nothing (they do no validation, no synchronization, no copying, no anything) are actually superfluous and we just code them because it is the convention in Java. But they serve no purpose. Other people (e.g.: Google) don't follow this convention blindly.

Newer languages usually provide some mechanism to automate the creation of these methods, or even skip them entirely, relying on the member access modifiers to provide encapsulation. For instance, [C#'s properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) provide automatic getter/setters but allow your code to call them as if they were public members.

Comment: I don't think performance is an issue at all; simple methods are usually inlined by the compiler - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion . Regarding code brevity, Java has Project Lombok which is pretty much like C# properties (although it is not part of the JDK).

Comment: The JIT compiler will most likely perform heavy inlining in a standard JVM. But there are platforms with no JIT, like Java ME's old KVM, and I wonder if the newer JavaME embedded supports it.